# Image gallery of variable size thumbnails

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a bootstrap image gallery where images have a maximum height/length but can be any size within the restrictions. I want the max-width and max-height to be percentages.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
        {% for reddit_post in reddit_posts %}
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 text-center">
            <div class="bottom-padded">
            <a class="modal-link">
               <center>
              <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" data-src="{{ reddit_post.thumbnail_link }}">  
              </center>
            </a>
          </div>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div><!--end row-->
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail {
    max-width:  75%;
    max-height: 45%;
}
```

For some reason, the gallery is skipping cells and images are not in the right place.

One thing to note, I am lazy-loading the images with Javascript.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: So is the HTML coding what is retrieved and then loaded by the lazy loading that you mentioned?

Comment: @MichaelFreake

I don't completely understand what you are asking but I'll try to give you and idea of what I am doing. I am creating a `<img>` with a `data-src` field containing the link to the thumbnail and no `href` field. 


On load, `<img>`s don't have any hrefs. When the user scrolls over the frame of an `<img>`, a script will copy the thumbnail link from `data-src` to the `href` of the `<img>`

Comment: that's exactly what I was wondering. Do you have an example to share? jsFiddle maybe?

Comment: @MichaelFreake

ya, I am using this little script: https://github.com/luis-almeida/unveil/blob/master/jquery.unveil.js